# What is the correct way to Create/Deploy SSRS Reports using SSDT

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, report-designer

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and Reporting services 2012.

I have recently inherited responsibility for a handful of SSRS reports which are stored on the server in their own grouped folders e.g.

```
<My Server>/MainFolder/SubFolder/reports
```

All reports have been edited using report builder directly from the interface until now.

What I would like to achieve is to be able to download all reports and add them to a reporting services project inside Visual Studio (2017). This wasnt too much of an issue, Once downloaded the shared data sets and sources needed to be updated.

The problem I have faced is that some of the reports use shared report parts on the server and a sub report that is in a different folder on SSRS.

I dont really want to add the sub reports into every project as it will be a nightmare to maintain.

Question:
What is the standard way of creating components that can be shared across several different projects so that i could create a structure similar to the example below.

```
- servername
    - MainFolder
      - Cars
          + report
      - Bikes
          + report
      - SharedAssets
          + subreport
```

With this structure if i nest the subreport in any of the reports in different projects/folders.

This seems pretty trivial and I am sure i have overlooked/misunderstood something so if anyone has some good resources then I will be very grateful!

Comment: You would think this was straightforward but it's not. AFAIK you cannot deploy to different folders from within a VS project. They way I have done it is to actually put all the reports in one big hidden folder, then have linked reports that the users see. When you deploy to the main folder, the linked reports will reflect the changes. Not ideal but the easiest way I found

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go and see how it goes